# As is/ as it is- meaning

Tags: grammar

Do **as is** and **as it/he/she/they is/are**  mean the same thing?

Here are a few sentences:

> He's very good looking **as (he) is**, he doesn't even have to try to impress me.
>   Things are good **as (they) are/ as is**.
>   Don't waste bread. We have 4 slices left **as (it) is**.

Are all the above sentence grammatically correct without the pronouns he/they/it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions starting "as.." tend to refer to the current state or condition of a person or thing.

I take your three examples in turn:

"He's very good looking as he is" means he is already very good looking and does not need cosmetic surgery, a new hairstyle, etc, whether to impress you or for some other reason (e.g. vanity).

If things are good as they are, they are good in their current condition or state. It is implied that no improvement is necessary and to attempt any may be misguided. To say "things are good as is" would be extremely informal, bordering on an error.

We use "as it is" as you have shown when things are already bad and we don't want them to get worse. We have four slices of bread left as it is (we only have a little bread and excessive consumption will make the situation worse). My boss said "I cannot give you leave tomorrow because we are short of staff. Three people are sick as it is".

You can omit 'it' from none of your examples. "As is" is a casual, informal,  idiomatic phrase meaning "without alteration or further work done; in its current state", sometimes used with a hyphen: as-is. Your house is nearly ready: you can wait a week for the painting to be completed, or you can accept it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if they "mean the same thing" or not depends on context. I doubt there is a general rule to apply.

As for your examples, I think you are trying to say:

> As very good looking **as he is**, he doesn't even have to try to impress me.

In this example *he* is required. It is not an *as is* situation since you are just describing the person..

> Things are good as **they are**.
>   Things are good **as is**.

In these examples, *they are* refers back to "things". This is also not an *as is* situation.
However *as is* is used correctly.

> Don't waste *the* bread. We have 4 slices left **as it is**.

Here, *as it is* refers to the current situation. If you tried to use *as is*, you would be trying to say that the quantity of bread is expected to change or not, which would change the meaning.
In phrasing like this, *as it is* is often placed at the beginning:

> **As it is**, we have 4 slices of bread left. Don't waste it.

Comment: When you're using the **things are good as they are/as is**, you say this is not an **as is** situation. Could you give me an example of what an **as is** situation is?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96698/is-as-is-grammatically-correct?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Take a look at Rimmer's answer.
He states **as is** refers to something being in its current state, which doesn't go with what you say with the last example, "If you tried to use as is, you would be trying to say that the quantity of bread is expected to change or not, which would change the meaning."